# how we can describe 3 incoming current at one node?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

I know KCL is saying that at any node in closed circuit incoming current must equal to outgoing current. but I want to do analysis on this circuit, but the picture confused me, because there are 3 incoming current direction.[image]

and in first Figure how 2 current in one line (i2 and i3) be opposite direction ?
Can anyone help me to imagine (or figure out) ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hi im not asking to solve my homework. I am asking to help me to understand HOW 3 CURRENT CAN DIRECT TO ONE NODE without outgoing current ? I think its general question that many students stucked for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrows in the diagrams are conventions.  If the current is moving in the same direction as the arrow, then it's a positive current.  If the current is moving in the opposite direction, then it is negative current.

The arrows don't affect the behavior of the circuit (it would behave the same way even if no arrows were drawn).  It just lets you give an answer without having to also give the direction.

You're correct that you will not have a node where all paths to the node send current inward.

Comment: so how i can write a current equation for the node ? `i_1 + i_2 + i_4 =0` is this correct ?

Comment: @user3371196 Yes, this is correct. At leaast one current will have a negative value where "negative"simply means going against the direction of the arrow. These arrows are there arbitrary. Actual currents may be reversed.